# Running portable web services application server

Tags: java, web-services

I need portable container for running web services as server. JSON as a response. The server application must be able to start up using .bat script under Windows. Machine running the server must have only Java Runtime Enviroment installed, no other stuff required.

Axis2 on top of Tomcat do not seem like simple portable web server. What are the other alternatives?

**UPDATE:**
How come no one offered?

```
com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
```

and

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory;
```

Answer (score 2):

[Jetty](http://www.hascode.com/2013/07/embedding-jetty-or-tomcat-in-your-java-application/) is a good option.

Another very lightweight option is [fluent-http](https://github.com/CodeStory/fluent-http).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with Axis2, but as far as I know you can use embedded tomcat to achieve this with whichever frameworks you please.

Take a look at the tomcat maven plugin which I believe will even generate your application as a jar containing embedded tomcat in the latest version.